# Application that changed for different resolutions

Tags: c#, wpf, resolution

I am creating a new application on WPF using C#, (Visual Studio) however when i transfer my application to a different computer with a different resolution/screen size the application is too big for the page. Is there a way to make all of the application/buttons re size for the monitor resolution?

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find any related posts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to keep your application fit to the screen.
WPF gives you very effective tool to deal with it, call
 `<Viewbox> put your all controls inside </Viewbox>`

read this and try
[View Box Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SizeToContent` property of the window to size it to its contained items (i.e., `WidthAndHeight`), rather than some fixed size which in your case is larger than the monitor resolution of the "different computer."